# constructor cannot be applied to given types in Java

Tags: java, constructor

This class is responsible for receiving as an input parameter a `EditText` which will be converted to`Double` through a method of the parent class (this method `convertToDouble` is implemented in another class). After this this new value in `Double` should be passed to the`addToListCelsius` parent class method.

```
 public class TemperatureInCelsius extends TemperatureMain {

     public Double auxDouble;
     public EditText tempCel;

     public TemperatureInCelsius(Double _auxDouble, EditText _tempCel){
         auxDouble = _auxDouble;
         tempCel = _tempCel;
     }

     public void setTemperature (EditText tempCel) {

         super.convertToDouble(tempCel);
         auxDouble = super.getDoubleVal();

         super.addToListCelsius(auxDouble);
     }
 }
```

The class TemperatureMain

```
public class TemperatureMain {

    public String valString = "";
    public double val;
    public Map<String, List<Double>> temperatureDic = new Hashtable<>();
    public int i=0;

    public List<Object> listCelsius = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Object> listFahreneit = new ArrayList<>();

    public double getDoubleVal() { return val; }

    public List getListCelsius(){ return listCelsius; }

    public List getListFahr(){ return  listFahreneit; }


    public Map<String, List<Double>> getDictionary(){ return temperatureDic;       }

    public void convertToDouble (EditText aux){
        valString = aux.getText().toString();
        val = Double.parseDouble(valString);
    }

    public void addToListCelsius(Object valueList){
        listCelsius.add(valueList);
        System.out.println("Lista de C: " + listCelsius);
    }

    public void addToListFahreneit(Object valueList){
        listFahreneit.add(valueList);
        System.out.println("Lista de F:" + listFahreneit);
    }

    public void addDictionary (){   
        temperatureDic.put("C", getListCelsius());
        temperatureDic.put("F", getListFahr());
        System.out.println("Dicionário de temperaturas:" + temperatureDic);
    }
}
```

AddTemperature

```
public class AddTemperature extends AppCompatActivity {    
    EditText tempCel, tempFar, printIteration;
    Button listTemp, iterations;
    int numberIterations;

    public TemperatureInCelsius temperatureInCelsius = new TemperatureInCelsius();
    public TemperatureInFar temperatureInFar = new TemperatureInFar();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__temperature);

        tempCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_addCelsius);
        tempFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_addFar);
        printIteration = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_totalIteration);
        printIteration.setEnabled(false);

        iterations = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_iterations);
        listTemp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listTemp);

        iterations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //enviar valor(es) da(s) temperatura(s) para a classe TemperatureMain caaso tenham sido introduzidos
                if (tempCel.getText().length() != 0 || tempFar.getText().length() != 0){
                    if (tempFar.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added celsius temperature.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        temperatureInCelsius.setTemperature(tempCel);
                        numberIterations += 1;

                        //limpar o edit text
                        tempCel.getText().clear();
                    }
                    else if (tempCel.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added Fahrenheit temperature.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        temperatureInFar.setTemperature(tempFar);
                        numberIterations += 1;

                        tempFar.getText().clear();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added temperatures.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        temperatureInCelsius.setTemperature(tempCel);
                        temperatureInFar.setTemperature(tempFar);
                        numberIterations += 2;

                        tempCel.getText().clear();
                        tempFar.getText().clear();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please, introduce a temperature values.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                System.out.println("Iterações:" + numberIterations);
                printIteration.setText(Integer.toString(numberIterations));
            }
        });

        listTemp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent listTemp_activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListTemperature.class);
                startActivity(listTemp_activity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this way does not compile. The error that arises is the following

> "TemperatureInCelsius constructor in class TemperatureInCelsius cannot
>   be applied to given types".

Comment: Can you also show `TemperatureMain`?

Comment: of course I can.

Comment: At which line you are getting error? Because in current code there is no code, where you are initializing TemperatureInCelsius object.

Comment: The error is in the console, in build output. In the code no error arises, just does not compile.

Comment: So there should be some another code, where you are creating object, it would be great if you can share that.

Comment: OK sorry. I didn't understand, sorry. I create the object in the `AddTemperature` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your code you are creating Object of `TemperatureInCelsius` as below:

```
public TemperatureInCelsius temperatureInCelsius = new TemperatureInCelsius(); // 4th line in AddTemperatureclass
```

In Java when you don't define any constructor, default constructor is automatically added to Class (in your case `TemperatureInCelsius()`). But as soon as you define a constructor with parameter(s), default constructor is not added automatically. So if you want it you need to add it explicitly as you have added a constructor with parameters as  `public TemperatureInCelsius(Double _auxDouble, EditText _tempCel)`.

While in your code you are trying to create object using default contructor `TemperatureInCelsius()`. Which actually does not exists. So you are getting the error.

So solution is:

1) Define a default constructor explicitly in the `TemperatureInCelsius` class.

2) Or use parametarized constructor to create object.